# Standard keyboard keys not working on USB keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a USB keyboard that can do all of the extended keys but will not work on the regular keys.

I believe this to be a registry error problem.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is the computer's fault, and not the keyboard's? Try using it on another machine.

Comment: Sounds like the Ctrl or Shift key is buggered / stuck.

Answer (score 1):

One of four things are defective and each can be "easily" tested.

- The keyboard is defective. All you have to do is plug the device into another computer and see if it still doesn't work. (as suggested by Chris Dwyer)
- The USB controller is having problems. When you first turn on the computer, before you load windows, there is a moment that you can enter the BIOS. Try hitting the keyboard button to do so and navigate around the menu if possible. If the keyboard works on another computer but is non-responsive on the pre-windows environment, then the system has problems.
- A piece of software or a utility is disabling the keyboard. Boot into safe mode and see if the keyboard works. This of course assumes that you are running a windows OS and that the dive works elsewhere. If it works in safe mode and not in normal windows, then you might have bigger problems. Check for malicious software and reinstall the keyboard utility.
- The USB drivers in the OS are screwed up. There is no easy way to fix this. The main problem is that the only way to test this is reinstall your OS. It's a rather destructive step to test a keyboard.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, try plugging your keyboard into another computer to see if it's the computer's fault or the keyboard's.